# The best way to save large data in an Android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to create an Android app which contains a book with chapters and navigations.

Is the best way to save all of the books data in `SQLite` which contains, for example, `id`, `chapters`, etc.?

The book contains about 500 pages.

Comment: External server is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Like hardik joshi says, the limitation of the database is in the amount of space in your device, that's the limit. Obviously you cant reach it, but your database can be as larger as you need.

If you have to store a very large amount of data, you can store it in a database on a server, and connect from your device to that server and save the content in your device database on demand.

You can use files to store the data too, but I think this is an old method with more complications than others.

Other option is the Android element called Preferences, but that is for key/value pairs of primitive data, I don't know that this element can help you.

A good reference of this topic:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally Android offers numbers of options to save application data but the option you select depends on your exact needs as well as how much space your data requires. If you want to store structured data in a private database then SQLite is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good solution.
But you need tell more details. What's the format of data? It's just pure text? Or every page is one database entry row which is related to chapter?